Using the Windows task scheduler with an GUI and without an active session
I have a program that only runs on Windows and has no API, I need to log into it and export a csv file every day.
Using PyAutoGui I automated the entire process, but I can't get it to run with the task scheduler
Windows without an active session. If I'm logged in it works but when I'm logged out it doesn't work, it needs a GUI to work.
I've tried all the processes to modify Windows' remote desktop so it never shuts down, among other methods.
but nothing works. Has anyone been through this and knows how to help me?
all solutions found on the internet.
